# HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Failed to parse Date value 'I'

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, spring-boot

The following is the code,json file and the exception I am getting while executing the code.

//Code

```
private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ShiftPlannerModel[]> {
            @Override
            protected ShiftPlannerModel[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                    ResponseEntity<ShiftPlannerModel[]> greeting = restTemplate.getForEntity(URL, ShiftPlannerModel[].class);
                    Log.i(greeting.getBody().toString(), "doInBackground: ");
                    return greeting.getBody();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("doInBackgrouExcp", e.getMessage(), e);
                }
```

Below code is for Model object and mapping values:

```
    @JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public class ShiftPlannerModel {

    ShiftPlannerModel(){}

    @JsonFormat
            (shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date shiftPlannerDate;
    private String resourceName;
    private String shiftName;


    public ShiftPlannerModel(Date shiftPlannerDate, String resourceName, String shiftName) {
        this.shiftPlannerDate = shiftPlannerDate;
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
        this.shiftName = shiftName;
    }

 //setters and getters
    public static ArrayList<ShiftPlannerModel> fromJson(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        JSONObject businessJson;
        ArrayList<ShiftPlannerModel> businesses = new ArrayList<ShiftPlannerModel>(jsonArray.length());
        // Process each result in json array, decode and convert to business object
        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                businessJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }

            ShiftPlannerModel business = ShiftPlannerModel.fromJson(businessJson);
            if (business != null) {
                businesses.add(business);
            }
        }

        return businesses;
    }
    // Decodes business json into business model object
    public static ShiftPlannerModel fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        ShiftPlannerModel shiftPlannerModel = new ShiftPlannerModel();
        // Deserialize json into object fields
        try {
//            shiftPlannerModel.resource = jsonObject.getString("resourceName");
//            shiftPlannerModel.ShiftName = jsonObject.getString("resourceId");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date workingDays = sdf.parse(jsonObject.getString("shiftPlannerDate"));
//            shiftPlannerModel.shiftPlannerDate = workingDays;

            shiftPlannerModel.setResourceName(jsonObject.getString("resourceName"));
            shiftPlannerModel.setShiftName(jsonObject.getString("shiftName"));
            shiftPlannerModel.setShiftPlannerDate(workingDays);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return new object
        return shiftPlannerModel;
    }
}
```

//json

```
  [
        [
            "2018-04-16",
            "Elias",
            "I"
        ],
        [
            "2018-04-16",
            "Sithik",
            "II"
        ],
        [
            "2018-04-17",
            "Vijay",
            "II"
        ],
----------------------------
```

//Exception while reading the above JSON format

> 04-18 07:07:09.089 31444-31460/? E/doInBackgrouExcp: Could not read JSON: Failed to parse Date value 'I' (format: "yyyy-MM-dd"):
>   Unparseable date: "I" (through reference chain:
>   com.example.admin.myapplication.ShiftPlannerModel["shiftPlannerDate"]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to parse
>   Date value 'I' (format: "yyyy-MM-dd"): Unparseable date: "I" (through
>   reference chain:
>   com.example.admin.myapplication.ShiftPlannerModel["shiftPlannerDate"])
>               org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read JSON: Failed to parse Date value 'I' (format:
>   "yyyy-MM-dd"): Unparseable date: "I" (through reference chain:
>   com.example.admin.myapplication.ShiftPlannerModel["shiftPlannerDate"]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to parse
>   Date value 'I' (format: "yyyy-MM-dd"): Unparseable date: "I" (through
>   reference chain:
>   com.example.admin.myapplication.ShiftPlannerModel["shiftPlannerDate"])

Comment: so it looks like you code is mistaking the third field for the second field, why don't you show the code that has the problem?

Comment: Hi Scary edited my question with model object.

Comment: Are you sure that is valid JSON?

Answer (score 1):

ThanksAlot Scary Wombat!

My bad I have checked it everything but didn't notice that webservice which I am consuming is not in Json format. I will change webservices so that it will return in json format.